# Experimenting with a Walkie Talkie

Tags: power-supply, power, rf, emc, interference

This is one weird bizarre thing which I noticed while I was in the electronics lab.

I had this [Power Supply](https://www.tanotis.com/products/gw-instek-gpc-3030d-bench-power-supply-adjustable-fixed-3-output-0-v-30-v-0-a-3-a?gclid=CjwKCAiA58fvBRAzEiwAQW-hzUrM9AzCdB49PlD2KVd6XBbUNMWfgHOZZogEVxtDr9FcMB37DwRqXhoCyaQQAvD_BwE) and a walkie talkie similar to [this](https://www.amazon.in/Baofeng-BF-888s-Intelligent-Illumination-Flashlight/dp/B075TZ3SPS/ref=asc_df_B075TZ3SPS/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397082166929&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1071190761023243061&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007809&hvtargid=pla-570649997415&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi)

I have not ventured in RF side yet.

The power supply was ON and unconnected to anything. It was reading 13V constant and no load current was taken. When I took the walkie talkie and turned ON (I don't know what frequency it was transmitting , but there was a display on the walkie talkie which read 63 - CH). When I took this walkie talkie near the power supply, I could see the voltage value changing from 13V to 19V to 9V and so on. It was randomly changing value.

I took a multimeter and measured the output voltage while the voltage was changing, I noticed that only the display LEDs on the power supply was changing as the multimeter measured 13.2V.

What could be the reason for this?

Sorry, as I could not provide more information regarding the frequency of the walkie talkie as I am not into RF. Just ventured into the LAB and found this bizarre thing.

Comment: Sounds like you were creating radio frequency interference to the built in meter. Note that those radios are **almost certainly illegal for you to use** without a license which you *obviously do not have*.

Comment: A similar effect happens with a cell phone near a computer, or a powered loudspeaker. The relatively high-power signal is rectified and detected by some IC's, producing *beeps* each time the phone tries to connect to a tower.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Seems liable to be in India. What do you base your "... obviously do not ... " on? I'm not saying you are wrong - it's just not obvious to me. From the little I know of India and my small (non - zero) experience there I'd lean towards you being correct. But ...?

Comment: Chris:  the product reviews are pretty clear - this is a $25 FRS radio; no license required in the US and most of Europe.

Comment: Can someone explain me the answer / process of what's happening near the power supply and @DrMoishePippik , could  you please explain what is the relatively high power signal and where it is coming from?

Comment: @Analogkid no, it isn't an FRS radio, though it overlaps with those frequencies the power level drastically exceeds FRS allowances.  The reviews claiming it is FRS are wrong, it is for licensed users only.  Look up the model number elsewhere

Comment: Deleting this post due to no clear answers. Receiving only sketchy comments. Don't know why its hard for someone to help with atleast a moderate answer for this question. I have given as much input I know to this question. Users commenting about the license and stuff rathering than helping atleast something with the answer for this question, just makes a fool of this effort put in the question. Thank you all

Comment: Was going to write an answer but if the question is going to be deleted I'm not going to bother. Answer summary: The voltage display of the supply is very likely disturbed by the presence of the RF signals from the Walkie-Talkies. It is easy for some Amplitude detection to happen in non-RF circuits when enough RF signal is getting in. Similar to audio equipment making weird noises when a cell phone is operating nearby.

Comment: @Newbie - the license issue is actually quite relevant to the RFI issue; most of the point of requiring licenses is to create a responsibility for avoiding interference.  The process of obtaining an amateur radio license (which is typically the only way to individually gain authorization to use such a radio) explicitly includes demonstrating an understanding of radio frequency interference.